# S3 Batch / Parallel Upload Error with PHP SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I followed these codes to batch `PutObject` into S3. I am using the latest PHP SDK (3.x). But I am getting:

> Argument 1 passed to Aws\AwsClient::execute() must implement interface Aws\CommandInterface, array given

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'images/1.jpg',
    'Body' => base64_decode( 'xxx' ),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));

$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'images/2.jpg',
    'Body' => base64_decode( 'xxx' ),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));

// Execute the commands in parallel
$s3->execute($commands);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a modern version of the SDK, try building the command this way, instead. Taken straight from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-commands.html); it should work. This is called the "chaining" method.

```
$commands = array();


$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject')
                ->set('Bucket', $bucket)
                ->set('Key', 'images/1.jpg')
                ->set('Body', base64_decode('xxx'))
                ->set('ACL', 'public-read')
                ->set('ContentType', 'image/jpeg');

$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject')
                ->set('Bucket', $bucket)
                ->set('Key', 'images/2.jpg')
                ->set('Body', base64_decode('xxx'))
                ->set('ACL', 'public-read')
                ->set('ContentType', 'image/jpeg');

// Execute the commands in parallel
$s3->execute($commands);

// Loop over the commands, which have now all been executed
foreach ($commands as $command)
{
    $result = $command->getResult();

    // Use the result.
}
```

Make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK.

**Edit**

It appears that the SDK's API has changed significantly in Version 3.x. The above example should work correctly in Version 2.x of the AWS SDK. For 3.x, you need to use `CommandPool()`s and `promise()`:

```
$commands = array();

$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'images/1.jpg',
    'Body' => base64_decode ( 'xxx' ),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));
$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'images/2.jpg',
    'Body' => base64_decode ( 'xxx' ),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));


$pool = new CommandPool($s3, $commands);

// Initiate the pool transfers
$promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool to complete synchronously
try {
    $result = $promise->wait();
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // handle the error.
}
```

Then, `$result` should be an array of command results.

Comment: Isn't this the same as I have coded? The error is failing at $s3->execute($commands);

Comment: The difference is the `->set()` chaining rather than the `array()` of parameters. What version are you using?

Comment: Didn't work. Using ## 3.0.4 - 2015-06-11. Call to undefined method Aws\Command::set()

Comment: I just added a new example for AWS SDK 3.x. They've made significant changes. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: The example will still fail at ->set('Bucket', $bucket)??

Comment: Sorry, an oversight on my part. Fixed!

Comment: Sweet! How shall I get the ObjectURL for each object?

Comment: I don't have an environment with the 3.0 SDK set up to test with, but, I believe $result will be an array of result arrays, so, something like `$result[0]['ObjectURL']` for the first one, and so on. Maybe `var_dump()` out `$result` to see what it contains, as I'm not totally sure about this part.

Comment: var_dump($result); shows NULL. will try to google :)

Comment: What happens if you change `$promise->wait()` to `$promise->wait(true)`?